# How can I measure the performance of any WordPress Plugin or Theme?

Tags: plugins, themes, performance, server-load

There are many WordPress plugin or themes with nearly same functionality and features but, how can I measure the performance of any plugin or WordPress theme other than using P3 profiler plugin?

I want to know the technical aspects such as resource usage, load time, code quality, impact on site performance etc.

Can any expert WordPress developer guide me on this?

Thanks

Comment: Nice question! Have you tried [Xdebug profiler](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1200214/how-can-i-measure-the-speed-of-code-written-in-php)?